# Show a error page in a PWA when it is offline

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I would like to show an error page when my PWA is offline. It's an application of only one page (index.hmtl) but in case of a user try to visit another page, show a html file called error.html.
This is the code I'm trying:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
    console.log('Fetch...', e);

    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(e.request)
            .then(resultCache => {
                return resultCache
            })
            .catch(() => cache.match('/error.html'))
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full answer here is complicated.
I do a few things.

1. Hook into the client online event and toggle from that
2. The online event is not 100% reliable as a phone may be connected to a cell tower, but no Internet connectivity. So if a fetch fails indicating we are offline I toggle the state.

Between the client layer and the service worker I post messages back and forth to indicate state changes. If the service worker knows the device is offline I intercept all document requests going to the cloud and return an offline response page.
I also use the offline state and inject a CSS class in the body.classList array to toggle some sort of visual to the user. One thing I love to do is apply a grayscale mask over the entire page like FlipKart does. But it could be a variety of visual queues.